# How to destroy dynamically created radiobutton in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

here i am trying to create radio buttons dynamically depend on the value of spinbox after changing the value of spin box and submitting the button no, radio button should be equal to that value which is present in spin box

```
from tkinter import *


dynamic_option=[]
val={}
dynamic_key=[]
flag=0;
no=0;
spin=0;
def set_value():
    global flag
    global dynamic_option
    global val
    global R1
    global R2
    global R3
    global dynamic_key
    d=40
    global no
    global spin
    c=120
    val={}
    print(flag)
    if flag==0:
        no=int(text1.get())
        for num in range(0,no):
            i=num
            val[i] = StringVar()
            R1="r1"+str(num)
            R2="r2"+str(num)
            R3="r3"+str(num)
            R1 = Radiobutton(myframe, text="Bad", variable=val[i], value="bad")
            R1.select()
            R1.place(x=330,y=c+20)
            R2 = Radiobutton(myframe, text="No Effect", variable=val[i], value="no effect")
            R2.place(x=380,y=c+20)
            R3 = Radiobutton(myframe, text="Good", variable=val[i], value="good")
            R3.place(x=460,y=c+20)
            dynamic_key.append(R1)
            dynamic_key.append(R2)
            dynamic_key.append(R3)
            dynamic_option.append(val[i])
            c=c+30
            spin=no+1;
            flag=1
    elif flag==1 :
        for num in range(0,spin):
            dynamic_key[num].destroy()
            dynamic_key[num+1].destroy()
            dynamic_key[num+2].destroy()


        flag=0
        dynamic_option=[]
        dynamic_key=[]
        print(flag)
        set_value()
myframe=Tk()
myframe.geometry("%dx%d" %(700,700))
text1=Spinbox(myframe, width=3,from_=0, to=12)
text1.place(x=270,y=110)
r=Button(myframe,width=10,pady=2,text="input",command=set_value)
r.place(x=330,y=110)
myframe.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would send the button number to a function when a button is changed.  This is a modification of the code found at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm  It prints the item in the MODE list instead of deleting from a list of the button objects, but the idea is the same.

```
from functools import partial

master = Tk()

MODES = [("Monochrome", "1"),
    ("Grayscale", "L"),
    ("True color", "RGB"),
    ("Color separation", "CMYK")]

def radio_callback(btn_num):
    print "button %sd pressed = %s" % (btn_num, MODES[btn_num])

v = StringVar()
v.set("L") # initialize

for ctr in range(len(MODES)):
    b_text, mode = MODES[ctr]
    b = Radiobutton(master, text=b_text,
                    variable=v, value=mode,
                    command=partial(radio_callback, ctr))
    b.pack(anchor=W)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: here i am trying to destroy the widget

Comment: here i am trying to destroy the widget